# Is a harmonic function with vanishing norm derivative on the boundary of its domain a constant function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

This question arose when I try to prove , although there's no maximal norm estimation for laplace equation with second boundary condition, the difference of two solutions of that equation can only be constant.

Comment: @qbert sorry for my poor English... Does the main part of the question make sense?

Comment: it's ok! just pointing it out for future.